# how to parse Json Array Inside Json Array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-json

I want to know how to parse JSON array inside into another JSON array.I am new in android developing please help me and Thanks in advance.[my web service url](http://opencart.codeniques.com/myshop/?route=feed/web_api/product&id=30&key=test123)
here my code:-

```
public class  ProductsAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... param){
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(param[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("product");

                for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Products products = new Products();

                    products.setId(jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                    products.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    products.setManufacturer(jsonObject1.getString("manufacturer"));
                    products.setModel(jsonObject1.getString("model"));
                    products.setReward(jsonObject1.getString("reward"));
                    products.setPoints(jsonObject1.getString("points"));
                    products.setImage(jsonObject1.getString("image"));
                    products.setPrice(jsonObject1.getString("price"));
                    products.setSpecial(jsonObject1.getString("special"));

                    JSONArray jArray1 = jArray.getJSONArray(i);

                    for(int j = 0;j<jArray1.length();j++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                        products.setDiscounts_quantity(jsonObject2.getString("quantity"));
                        products.setDiscounts_price(jsonObject2.getString("price"));
                    }
                    JSONArray jArray2 = jArray.getJSONArray(i);

                    for(int j = 0;j<jArray2.length();j++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(j);

                        products.setOptions_product_option_id(jsonObject2.getString("product_option_id"));
                        products.setOptions_option_id(jsonObject2.getString("option_id"));
                        products.setOptions_name(jsonObject2.getString("name"));
                        products.setOptions_type(jsonObject2.getString("type"));

                        JSONArray jsonArray3 = jArray2.getJSONArray(j);

                        for(int k = 0;k < jsonArray3.length();k++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(k);

                            products.setOptions_option_value_product_option_value_id(jsonObject3.getString("product_option_value_id"));
                            products.setOptions_option_value_option_value_id(jsonObject3.getString("option_value_id"));
                            products.setOptions_option_value_name(jsonObject3.getString("name"));
                            products.setOptions_option_value_image(jsonObject3.getString("image"));
                            products.setOptions_option_value_price(jsonObject3.getString("price"));
                            products.setOptions_option_value_price_prefix(jsonObject3.getString("price_prefix"));
                        }

                            products.setOptions_required(jsonObject2.getString("required"));
                    }

                            products.setMinimum(jsonObject1.getString("minimum"));
                            products.setRating(jsonObject1.getString("rating"));
                            products.setDescription(jsonObject1.getString("description"));

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);

                            for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length();j++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_group_id(jsonObject2.getString("attribute_group_id"));
                                products.setAttribute_groups_name(jsonObject2.getString("name"));

                                JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(j);

                                for(int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length();k++){

                                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);

                                    products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_attribute_id(jsonObject3.getString("attribute_id"));
                                    products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_name(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                    products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_text(jsonObject3.getString("text"));
                                }
                            }
                    productsList.add(products);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else if(status == 500){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){

        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data is not Parsed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.content_main,productsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new in android developing please help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your json structure

Comment: I gave a link of my json structure
http://opencart.codeniques.com/myshop/?route=feed/web_api/product&id=30&key=test123

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res.toString());
                if (jArray.length() == 0) {
                    txtNoDataFound1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtNoDataFound1.setText("No Data Found !!");
                    txtNoDataFound1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER
                            | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    expListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    ListHead.clear();
                    expListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        getheadingid = json.getString("Headid");

                        listhead = new ListHeaderEntity(json.getString("Headid"),
                                json.getString("HeadServiceTitle"));

                        try {
                            JSONArray jArray1 = json.getJSONArray("subServiceData");

                            if (jArray1.length() == 0) {
                            } else {
                                listhead.setListitems(new ArrayList<CityEntity>());
                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject json1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                                    CityEntity listitem = new CityEntity();
                                    listitem.setLblcityid(json1.getString("subid"));
                                    listitem.setLblcityname(json1.getString("servicedetailTitle"));
                                    listhead.getListitems().add(listitem);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception objEx) {
                            objEx.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        ListHead.add(listhead);
                    }
                    listAdapter = new ServiceExpandAdapter(
                            getActivity(), ListHead, expListView);
                    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    res1 = null;
                    selectedService.clear();
                    PutUtility objClient1 = new PutUtility();

                    try {
                        res1 = objClient1.getData("url");
                    } catch (Exception objEx) {
                        objEx.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(res1.toString());
                    if (jArray1.length() == 0) {
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                            //selectedvalue.add(Integer.parseInt(json.getString("subservice_id")));
                            int in=Integer.parseInt(json.getString("subservice_id"));
                                    selectedService.add(in);
                        }
                    }

                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception objEx) {
                objEx.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To take another array in an object you have to change

> JSONArray jArray1 = jArray.getJSONArray(i);

to

```
JSONArray jArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("discounts");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your json response "product" is not json array it is json object. Change like this in your `doInBackground()`.

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... param){
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(param[0]);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(status == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);


                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("product");

                Products products = new Products();

                products.setId(jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                products.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                products.setManufacturer(jsonObject1.getString("manufacturer"));
                products.setModel(jsonObject1.getString("model"));
                products.setReward(jsonObject1.getString("reward"));
                products.setPoints(jsonObject1.getString("points"));
                products.setImage(jsonObject1.getString("image"));
                products.setPrice(jsonObject1.getString("price"));
                products.setSpecial(jsonObject1.getString("special"));



                JSONArray jArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("discounts");

                for(int j = 0;j<jArray1.length();j++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                    products.setDiscounts_quantity(jsonObject2.getString("quantity"));
                    products.setDiscounts_price(jsonObject2.getString("price"));
                }
                JSONArray jArray2 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("options");

                for(int j = 0;j<jArray2.length();j++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(j);

                    products.setOptions_product_option_id(jsonObject2.getString("product_option_value_id"));
                    products.setOptions_option_id(jsonObject2.getString("option_id"));
                    products.setOptions_name(jsonObject2.getString("name"));
                    products.setOptions_type(jsonObject2.getString("type"));

                    JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("option_value");

                    for(int k = 0;k < jsonArray3.length();k++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(k);

                        products.setOptions_option_value_product_option_value_id(jsonObject3.getString("product_option_value_id"));
                        products.setOptions_option_value_option_value_id(jsonObject3.getString("option_value_id"));
                        products.setOptions_option_value_name(jsonObject3.getString("name"));
                        products.setOptions_option_value_image(jsonObject3.getString("image"));
                        products.setOptions_option_value_price(jsonObject3.getString("price"));
                        products.setOptions_option_value_price_prefix(jsonObject3.getString("price_prefix"));
                    }

                        products.setOptions_required(jsonObject2.getString("required"));
                }

                        products.setMinimum(jsonObject1.getString("minimum"));
                        products.setRating(jsonObject1.getString("rating"));
                        products.setDescription(jsonObject1.getString("description"));

                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("attribute_groups");

                        for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length();j++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                            products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_group_id(jsonObject2.getString("attribute_group_id"));
                            products.setAttribute_groups_name(jsonObject2.getString("name"));

                            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("attribute");

                            for(int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length();k++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);

                                products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_attribute_id(jsonObject3.getString("attribute_id"));
                                products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_name(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                products.setAttribute_groups_attribute_text(jsonObject3.getString("text"));
                            }
                        }
                productsList.add(products);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if(status == 500){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject1 = jArray.getJSONObject("product");
This jArray??

Comment: That's my mistake changed jArray to jsonObject. Edited answer.

Comment: When i am trying your code its give a error JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90275/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-ved).

Answer (score -1):

Json will just parse the json file in to one json object and then you can just reference it.

Comment: i don't understand what are you trying to say please explain with example  @Cameron White